# Using vcovHC to random effects model in R - clustering by both time and entity?

Tags: r, panel-data

I have a random effects model about stock returns for different companies across several quarters. To handle clustered standard errors, I would like to use vcovHC and cluster by both company and quarter. I found several answers that would help to cluster a regular linear model by both dimensions but random effects would not be present, so asking for your help to include that.

Would the code below work for that or what would be your approach?

```
clustered_se <- vcovHC(random_model, type = "HC1", cluster = "group", group = "time")
coeftest(random_model, clustered_se)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question it remains unclear which R packages you use. I will assume you use `plm` for random effects model estimation and `lmtest::coeftest`.

Many packages bring a `vcovHC` implementation. If you use `plm::vcovHC`, this will not give you double-clustered standard error, see the documentation `?plm::vcovHC`. (The argument `cluster` indicates you use `plm::vcovHC`, but on the other hand argument `group` is invalid for `plm`´s `vcovHC`.)

For a plm-based approach, there is `plm::vcovDC` giving double-clustered standard errors a la Thompson (2011) and Cameron et al. (2011), see its documentation. So, if your data is quarterly (and quaterly is in the time dimension of your data), you can cluster by company and quarter with `vcovDC`.

An example looks like something along this lines (for, e.g., a two-ways RE model):

```
library(plm)
data("Grunfeld")
swar <- plm(inv ~ value + capital,
            data = Grunfeld, model = "random", effect = "twoways")
dblcluster <- vcovDC(swar)
summary(swar, vcov = dblcluster)
#
#
#> Twoways effects Random Effect Model 
#>    (Swamy-Arora's transformation)
#> 
#> Note: Coefficient variance-covariance matrix supplied: dblcluster
#> 
#> Call:
#> plm(formula = inv ~ value + capital, data = Grunfeld, effect = "twoways", 
#>     model = "random")
#> 
#> Balanced Panel: n = 10, T = 20, N = 200
#> 
#> Effects:
#>                   var std.dev share
#> idiosyncratic 2675.43   51.72 0.274
#> individual    7095.25   84.23 0.726
#> time             0.00    0.00 0.000
#> theta: 0.864 (id) 0 (time) 0 (total)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>      Min.   1st Qu.    Median   3rd Qu.      Max. 
#> -177.1700  -19.7576    4.6048   19.4676  252.7596 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>               Estimate Std. Error z-value  Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept) -57.865377  36.373180 -1.5909    0.1116    
#> value         0.109790   0.010657 10.3021 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> capital       0.308190   0.043926  7.0161 2.281e-12 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Total Sum of Squares:    2376000
#> Residual Sum of Squares: 547910
#> R-Squared:      0.7694
#> Adj. R-Squared: 0.76706
#> Chisq: 155.664 on 2 DF, p-value: < 2.22e-16
#
## with coeftest:
lmtest::coeftest(swar, vcov. = dblcluster, df = Inf)
#> 
#> z test of coefficients:
#> 
#>               Estimate Std. Error z value  Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept) -57.865377  36.373180 -1.5909    0.1116    
#> value         0.109790   0.010657 10.3021 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> capital       0.308190   0.043926  7.0161 2.281e-12 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

Comment: FYI: OP is not asking a programming question with [mre] that yields an error or undesired result relevant for StackOverflow, but a statistics question relevant for other StackExchange sites.

Comment: I see it rather on-topic here, i.e., rather a programming question as the OP is asking how to accomplish something with a programming language which she seems to have the statistical background to it, but did not manage to find an appropriate function and has not yet checked the documentation how to use the function(s) and supplies code.